# Recover from a corrupted couchbase install

Tags: corruption, couchbase

We have a couchbase installation on a Windows 2008 R2 server that got corrupted (this was from before my tenure, now I want to clean it up). There is no add-remove entry in the Programs and Features list. There is no active service in services.msc.

However, something still thinks Couchbase is installed. Shy of wiping the box (we aren't quite to "redeploy test environment servers at the push of a button" altho I'm working on it), how can I ensure that all remnants of couchbase installs prior are now gone?

I believe the previous install was in the Couchbase 2.x range, but it may have been 1.7+

Running the installer again gives "Installer needs to update registry value in order to upgrade from the previous version. Please run installer again to continue."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've been troubled by OP's installer message on my laptop for a bit, but got it to run a few minutes ago.

In addition to the lines suggested by John Zablocki I added lines for the installers in `Wow6432Node` since it's a 64 bit machine, even if I aren't sure it's needed.

The most important key is however the last one, the `UpgradeCode` left behind by an old or possibly failed install. The keyname will most likely vary depending on which version it was, so this might not be the right key name for you (if it aren't you can find it using `ProcMon`, the process name is `msiexec.exe`, even if it might take a bit of tech savvyness).

The below `.reg` file was what made the installer run for me, alternatively you can delete the keys manually:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer\Products\1456F12DAE7ED0B42BB0D4BDFA6588B2]
[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer\Products\CE2FC473EBF11FB488B05BA86825B28C]
[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\Installer\Products\1456F12DAE7ED0B42BB0D4BDFA6588B2]
[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\Installer\Products\CE2FC473EBF11FB488B05BA86825B28C]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer\UpgradeCodes\DAFE44492BF730D45B002C1133EA9A42]
```

Comment: Woohoo! Worked! Time to reconfigure some servers!

Answer (score 2):

There are two keys in the registry you should remove:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Classes\\Installer\\Products\\1456F12DAE7ED0B42BB0D4BDFA6588B2]
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Classes\\Installer\\Products\\CE2FC473EBF11FB488B05BA86825B28C]
```

If this doesn't allow the new installer to move forward, please let me know.

Comment: Removed, restarted the 1.8.1 x64 installer, it reinserts the keys and aborts just the same.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error on a machine that never attempted a couchbase install (2014-win 7) and has none of the registry keys or values in previous answers.

file: couchbase-server-enterprise_2.2.0_x86.setup.exe

I ended up just having to try a different linux server, this is an issue with couchbase install that they need to address, I recommend trying unix/linux or a different machine or a different machine and not windows